# GRAPE with Python?

Tags: optimization, qutip, quantum-control

I want to do some quick GRAPE calculations in Python. The qutip implementation is handy but I can't modify the fidelity function. However, I need to use my own fidelity function to evaluate fidelity. Are there other options or ways to use customize fidelity measure with qutip?

Comment: hey, let it qutip calculate the fidelity, you can also calculate your own fidelity. just take the final result by the comment ```result.evo_full_final``` (if I remember well, this is the final unitary) and then calculate your fidelity function

Comment: @quest Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying qutip for this purpose and it was kind of painful. There are several classes that need to be modified. You can check my repo for that version.
https://github.com/PiggsBoson/qutip